# execute binary file on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, exec

I'm trying to execute a binary file (file.bin) with a PHP script on my localhost on windows under Apache 2.4.3.

What I have tried:

```
<?php echo exec('c:\file.bin'); ?>
```

Besides `exec` i have tried `shell_exec` and `system`.

I gave to file.bin a a executable permissions for all users: (chmod a+x file.bin), in my linux. Then I passed the file.bin to my windows and also checked that it had execute permissions for all, and it has.
I also checked the file.bin on linux and its working just perfect: (./file.bin)

The problem:
What i get is that my browser keep waiting and don't show anything.

any ideas?

can i execute a bin file under Apache localhost that runs under windows?
if i cannot, is there any solution to running a bin file under windows?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can not act like this way. Despite all permissions - you're trying to execute linux binary file under Windows. That will not work since they are different by architecture. Win32 executables (`.exe`) have nothing to do with Linux binary files.

Possible solution - but only if you have source code of your binary Linux application - compile it under Windows/for Windows - this is the most correct way. Otherwise, there is [LBW](http://lbw.sourceforge.net/) project, which in most cases will allow you to do desired stuff.

Comment: @MatanTouti then, try to use `LBW` as I've suggested.